# Python: instantly decoding after encode

Tags: python, unicode

Found in legacy:

```
somevar.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```

Can we find this construction useful when *not* trying to catch encoding errors?

Comment: You are not normalising here, so I replaced the tag. No, round-tripping to UTF-8 has no impact.

Comment: Any string that can be represented in an encoding will round-trip happily. UTF-8 [can represent any Unicode code point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) which is specifically why it was designed, so this code should just be a rather expensive no-op.

Comment: It does make a difference in Python 2, right? After this the value returned is always Unicode, regardless of whether `somevar` was Python 2's `str`.

Comment: @SimeonVisser dont think so. Trying encoding `str` will likely raise `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimentation in Python 2.7.6 interpreter:

```
a = u"string"
a
```

Output: u'string'

```
b = a.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
b
```

Output: u'string'

```
b = a.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')
b
```

Output: 'string'

```
a = "string"
a
```

Output: 'string'

```
b = a.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
b
```

Output: u'string'

```
b = a.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')
b
```

Output: 'string'

Note that whether the original string is Unicode or not, the output of encode -> decode will be a Unicode string. The output of decode -> encode will not be a unicode string. A trivial note though, is that since strings are immutable, the code line as you posted it is useless for anything besides checking for UnicodeErrors because it doesn't catch the return value of the function calls.

The only real effect of the encode -> decode construct is that all strings passed through it (and caught from the return) will be Unicode strings. Why you would want to do this instead of `unicode_string = unicode(normal_string, encoding='UTF-8')` I have no idea.